# New to JavaScript using BlackBaud/Convio

Tags: javascript, blackbaud

I am using Blackbaud/Convio as a CRM. The images on my ecom site's catalog page are too small. I need to change the size from the thumbnail that the system creates to a higher resolution. I am very new in using JS and I need some help, if that is allowed.

Each page has different number of images, so I need to loop through them. This is a universal setting for all catalog pages.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<script>
  var myProducts = document.getElementsByClassName(“CatalogueProductImage”);
  myProducts[0].src = “../file path”;
</script>
```

Comment: Are the original images at a thumbnail size, or full size?  If the original images are thumbnail size, then you need to replace them with full size images.  If they are full size, then the rendered size on the screen will depend on your stylesheet.